# Does the messageId of a nacked message change?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

Does the messageId always change when it gets back to the queue after being nacked?
I've searched extensively through the docs and SO questions and found nothing about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message ID of a message never changes. The ack ID that comes on a subsequent delivery will change, though.